# How to resolve Method invocation 'toString' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'?

Tags: java, broadcastreceiver, uri

When i try to receive App when get an update with `Uri` i got this error.

On BroadcastReveiver.java

```
Uri packageName = new Intent ().getData ();

If (packageName.toString ().equals ("package:" + context.getPackagName ())){
//do something
}
```

`.toString` get error Method invocation 'toString' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Can someone help me or use batter way to receive App when get an update?

Comment: Error or warning?

Comment: If `packageName` can be null, do `String.valueOf(packageName)` instead of `packageName.toString()`.

Comment: you may check if packageName is not null : `if (null != packageName)`

Comment: @lambda Yoda conditions you like I see.